# Merge replication Error: The process could not bulk copy into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, merge-replication

Hi I am using SQL SERVER 2005 Service pack 4 on both publisher and distributor. While trying to setup merge replication, i am getting below error continuously. Below are replication details.

1. I am using push subscription and path is network path.
2. Distributer and publisher present on the same server.
3. I have restored recent backup on subscriber and 1 week back backup on publisher.
4. I am setting up replication for only few tables, procedures and user defined functions.
5. I have verified and both the publisher and subscriber are having same schema.
6. As the replication is failing initially saying unable to drop userdefined functions : To resolve it I have set publisher property for user defined functions as Keep existing object unchanged.
7. Every time the error is coming after running synchronization for around 50 to 55 minutes.
8. My snapshot agent is working fine without any issue. Problem is only with merge agent.
9. I have changed the verbosehistory value to 3 in merge agent profile but it is not giving any additional information

> Error messages: The merge process was unable to deliver the snapshot
>   to the Subscriber. If using Web synchronization, the merge process may
>   have been unable to create or write to the message file. When
>   troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history
>   logging and specify an output file to which to write. (Source:
>   MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)
>
> Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201001
>
> The process could not bulk copy into table
>   '"dbo"."refund_import_log"'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number:
>   MSSQL_REPL20037)
>
> Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20037
>
> The system cannot find the file specified. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error
>   number: 0)
>
> Get help: http://help/0
>
> To obtain an error file with details on the errors encountered when
>   initializing the subscribing table, execute the bcp command that
>   appears below.  Consult the BOL for more information on the bcp
>   utility and its supported options. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number:
>   20253)
>
> Get help: http://help/20253
>
> bcp "greyhound"."dbo"."refund_import_log" in
>   "\usaz-ism-db-02\ghstgrpltest\unc\USAZ-ISM-DB-02_GREYHOUND_GREYHOUND-STAGE\20150529112681\refund_import_log_7.bcp"
>   -e "errorfile" -t"\n\n" -r"\n<,@g>\n" -m10000 -SUSGA-QTS-GT-01 -T -w (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 20253)

**Here i am getting problem with different table every time.**

Is there any bug related to it ? If so where i can get the fix ? If it is not a bug then please let me know how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the problem:

```
The process could not bulk copy into table '"dbo"."refund_import_log"'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20037)
```

It then gives you a perfectly good repro, to see why bulk copy is failing:

```
bcp "greyhound"."dbo"."refund_import_log" in "\usaz-ism-db-02\ghstgrpltest\unc\USAZ-ISM-DB-02_GREYHOUND_GREYHOUND-STAGE\20150529112681\refund_import_log_7.bcp" -e "errorfile" -t"\n\n" -r"\n<,@g>\n" -m10000 -SUSGA-QTS-GT-01 -T -w
```

Looking at the bcp repro above, can you please doublecheck the UNC path that you set for the snapshot folder, it looks incorrect to me.  UNC paths should have two forward slashes in the beginning, yours only has one.  The UNC path should look like this:

```
\\usaz-ism-db-02\ghstgrpltest\unc\
```

Comment: Greg, I have given the path as \\usaz-ism-db-02\ghstgrpltest and snapshot agent is running fine without any errors..Problem is there only with merge agent